# Tuning recommendations for Mirroring on Workload Scheduler 9.x

Tags: websphere, mirroring, workload-scheduler

What are some tuning recommendations for mirroring with Workload Scheduler 9.x

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help. (Sounds like it might be on topic at [sf])

Comment: Will, thanks for the response.  Can you tell me if you can link Stack Overflow to ServerFault?  Also how do we create a tag for ServerFault

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER - This is a possible solution but each customer environment is different and may require additional tuning.  It is suggested to contact Workload Scheduler Support team to discuss any configuration changes.

**TUNING**

- Use Oracle jdbc type 4 as the datasource object type in WebSphere.
  This has already been done as I understand.
- Change maxThreads from 10 to 50 in the file resources-pme.xml. Add
  cacheSize parameter to TWSConfig.properties file
- Tune the datasource connection pool settings for minConnections and
  maxConnections in resources.xml

**Change maxThreads from 10 to 50 in the file resources-pme.xml.**

**Location:** *TWA_HOME/WAS/TWSProfile/config/cells//nodes/DefaultNode/servers//resources-pme.xml*

Create a backup copy of resources-pme.xml and then change line:

From:

factories xmi:type="workmanager:WorkManagerInfo" xmi:id="WorkManagerInfo_Default" name="DefaultWorkManager" jndiName="wm/default" description="WebSphere Default WorkManager" category="Default" minThreads="1" maxThreads="10" threadPriority="5" numAlarmThreads="5" isGrowable="false" workReqQFullAction="0"

To:

factories xmi:type="workmanager:WorkManagerInfo" xmi:id="WorkManagerInfo_Default" name="DefaultWorkManager" jndiName="wm/default" description="WebSphere Default WorkManager" category="Default" minThreads="1" maxThreads="50" threadPriority="5" numAlarmThreads="5" isGrowable="false" workReqQFullAction="0"

**Tune the datasource connection pool settings for minConnections and maxConnections in resources.xml.**

Location:

*TWA_HOME/WAS/TWSProfile/config/cells//nodes/DefaultNode/servers//resources.xml*

Create a backup copy of resources.xml and then change the line:

connectionPool xmi:id="ConnectionPool_1493330406573" connectionTimeout="180" maxConnections="30" minConnections="1" reapTime="180" unusedTimeout="1800" agedTimeout="0" purgePolicy="EntirePool" numberOfSharedPoolPartitions="0" numberOfUnsharedPoolPartitions="0" numberOfFreePoolPartitions="0" freePoolDistributionTableSize="0" surgeThreshold="-1" surgeCreationInterval="0" testConnection="true" testConnectionInterval="15" stuckTimerTime="0" stuckTime="0" stuckThreshold="0"/

To:

connectionPool xmi:id="ConnectionPool_1493330406573" connectionTimeout="180" maxConnections="50" minConnections="0" reapTime="180" unusedTimeout="1800" agedTimeout="0" purgePolicy="EntirePool" numberOfSharedPoolPartitions="0" numberOfUnsharedPoolPartitions="0" numberOfFreePoolPartitions="0" freePoolDistributionTableSize="0" surgeThreshold="-1" surgeCreationInterval="0" testConnection="true" testConnectionInterval="15" stuckTimerTime="0" stuckTime="0" stuckThreshold="0"/

**Add cacheSize parameter to TWSConfig.properties file.**

Open the file TWSConfig.properties:

com.ibm.tws.planner.monitor.cachesize=20000

***All these settings take effect after restarting the TWS WebSphere server instance.***